# Why are parentheses optional when using print in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, printing

In Python 2.7 both the following will do the same

```
print("Hello, World!") # Prints "Hello, World!"

print "Hello, World!" # Prints "Hello, World!"
```

However the following will not

```
print("Hello,", "World!") # Prints the tuple: ("Hello,", "World!")

print "Hello,", "World!" # Prints the words "Hello, World!"
```

In Python 3.x parenthesis on `print` is mandatory, essentially making it a function, but in 2.7 both will work with differing results. What else should I know about `print` in Python 2.7?

---

<sub>**See also**: [Getting SyntaxError for print with keyword argument end=' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148) for another consequence in Python 2.x of the difference in `print` handling.</sub>

Comment: In Python 2.x `print` is actually a special statement, not a function. This is also why it can't be used like: `lambda x: print x` Note that `(expr)` does not create a Tuple (it results in `expr`), but `,` does.

Comment: I'm assuming the support for print as a function and print as a statement is to maintain backwards compatibility with older versions of python while encouraging people to use the new syntax to migrate towards python 3.

Comment: p.s., To enable the print function in 2.7 (and not have the print statement behavior), you have to do a future import: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: Will the second example will in fact print "Hello,World!" (without the space) or will it print "Hello, World!" (with the space) as in the example.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

In Python 2.x `print` is actually a special statement and not a function*.

This is also why it can't be used like: `lambda x: print x`

Note that `(expr)` does not create a Tuple (it results in `expr`), but `,` does. This likely results in the confusion between `print (x)` and `print (x, y)` in Python 2.7

```
(1)   # 1 -- no tuple Mister!
(1,)  # (1,)
(1,2) # (1, 2)
1,2   # 1 2 -- no tuple and no parenthesis :) [See below for print caveat.]
```

However, since `print` is a *special syntax statement/grammar construct* in Python 2.x then, without the parenthesis, it treats the `,`'s in a special manner - and *does not* create a Tuple. This special treatment of the `print` statement enables it to act differently if there is a trailing `,` or not.

Happy coding.

---

*This `print` behavior in Python 2 can be changed to that of Python 3:

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Comment: Thanks for the `(expr) != tuple` explanation :-)

Answer (score 5):

It's all very simple and has nothing to do with forward or backward compatibility.

The general form for the `print` statement in all Python versions before version 3 is:

```
print expr1, expr2, ... exprn
```

(Each expression in turn is evaluated, converted to a string and displayed with a space between them.)

But remember that putting parentheses around an expression is still the same expression.

So you can also write this as:

```
print (expr1), (expr2), ... (expr3)
```

This has nothing to do with calling a function.

Comment: This is a perfectly correct answer, I'm not sure why it was downvoted so much either.

Comment: It's not about ``print (expr1), (expr2), ... (expr3)``, it is about why ``print (expr1, expr2, ... , expr3)`` is legal in python 2.x while it shouldn't be according to 2.x standards.

Answer (score 5):

Here we have interesting side effect when it comes to UTF-8.

```
>> greek = dict( dog="σκύλος", cat="γάτα" )
>> print greek['dog'], greek['cat']
σκύλος γάτα
>> print (greek['dog'], greek['cat'])
('\xcf\x83\xce\xba\xcf\x8d\xce\xbb\xce\xbf\xcf\x82', '\xce\xb3\xce\xac\xcf\x84\xce\xb1')
```

The last print is tuple with hexadecimal byte values.

Comment: I assume that's because print prints UTF-8 correctly, but when it receives a tuple, like your last print, it runs `repr` on it, at which point it probably encodes all strings in the dict to ASCII.

Comment: @Codemonkey, you are right about __repr__. You are wrong about ASCII. ASCII is default encoding for Python. But I have at the beginning of Python script `#encoding=utf-8`, linux env `LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. So __repr__ encodes not using default ASCII, but utf-8 encoding.

Comment: Repr encodes `str` with the special `string_escape` encoding. The string was already unicode encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @KarloSmid: What I meant to say was that `repr` probably takes steps to ensure that the text *can* be represented by ASCII (by means of escaping non-ASCII symbols), not necessarily that the string *is* encoded as ASCII. I still don't know if that's completely accurate though.

Comment: *All* Python containers (list, dict, tuple, set) include their contents as `repr()` output when converted to a string (they don't implement `__str__`, only `__repr__`). What you see is not special to UTF-8; the `repr()` of a string gives you valid Python string literals that are ASCII-safe.

Comment: Does this depend on whether it is [UTF-8](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8), [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16), or [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32)?

Answer (score 3):

Basically in Python before Python 3, print was a special statement that printed all the strings if got as arguments.  So `print "foo","bar"` simply meant "print 'foo' followed by 'bar'".  The problem with that was it was tempting to act as if print were a function, and the Python grammar is ambiguous on that, since `(a,b)` is a tuple containing `a` and `b` but `foo(a,b)` is a call to a function of two arguments.

So they made the incompatible change for 3 to make programs less ambiguous and more regular.

(Actually, I think 2.7 behaves as 2.6 did on this, but I'm not certain.)

Comment: No it wasn't "tempting" to use it as a function. :) However, it was impossible to use it as a function, so you can't do [print x for x in alist] for example.