# Regex Search and replace including rest of the line in brackets

Tags: regex, vim

I have some python code with many lines like this:

```
print "some text" + variables + "more text and special characters .. etc"
```

I want to modify this to put everything after print within brackets, like this:

```
print ("some text" + variables + "more text and special characters .. etc")
```

How to do this in vim using regex?

Comment: This below link might help you! 
<http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7>

Answer (score 2):

Use this substitute:

```
%s/print \(.*$\)/print (\1)
```

`\(.*$\)` matches everything up to the end of the line and captures it in a group using the escaped parentheses. The replacement includes this group using `\1`, surrounded by literal parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

```
:%s/print \(.*\)/print(\1)/c
```

OR if you visually select multiple lines

```
:'<,'>s/print \(.*\)/print(\1)/c
```

`%` - every line
`'<,'>` - selected lines
`s` - substitute
`c` - confirm - show you what matched before you convert
`print \(.*\)` - exactly match print followed by a space then group everything between the `\(` and `\)`
`print(\1)` - replace with print(<first match>)

Vim has some function rules for regex, you can do `:help substitute` or `:help regex` to see what they are.