# Why can print("string", object) give different results than print(object)?

Tags: python

I have defined this class:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __str__(self):
        return "Point x: {0}, Point y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
```

What is the difference between the 2 cases `print("Point",p1)` and `print(p1)`:

```
p1 = Point(1,2)
print("Point",p1)
print(p1)

>>('Point', <__main__.Point instance at 0x00D96F80>)
>>Point x: 1, Point y: 2
```

Answer (score 12):

The former is printing a tuple containing `"Point"` and `p1`; in this case `__repr__()` will be used to generate the string for output instead of `__str__()`.

Comment: This would be different if it were on Python 3, though. Or if the "print_function" future is used .. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7

Comment: why should there be a difference in printing p1 when we have __str__()

Comment: Because sequences don't print the string value of their elements, they print the representation.

Answer (score 6):

If you are using python2.x, then where you think you are calling print like a function, you are really printing a tuple, using the print keyword...

```
print(1,2,3)
print (1,2,3)
```

In python3, you have to do it like a function call `print(1,2,3)`.

So in your case, in python2.x, what you are printing is a tuple of values. Tuple tuple object will be converted to a string, and each value in the tuple will have its representation printed. When you print them as this: `print "Point",p1`, then each item will be converted to a string and printed.

```
print str(p1)
# Point x: 1, Point y: 2

print repr(p1)
# <__main__.Point instance at 0x00D96F80>
```

You would actually probably want to use `__repr__` instead of `__str__`:

```
class Point():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def __repr__(self):
        return "Point x: {0}, Point y: {1}".format(self.x, self.y)
```