# significance of using print() in python

Tags: python

What is the difference between using `print()` and not using it.

For example, say `a = ("first", "second", "third')`, what is the difference between

```
print (a[0] a[2])
```

and

```
a[0] a[2]
```

?

Comment: `a=("first", "second","third'),` syntax error correct it "third"

Comment: `print (a[0] a[2])` an error you should write `print (a[0], a[2])`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is parenthesis in print voluntary in Python 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the question is about using *print* not about using *parenthesis with print*.

Answer (score 6):

```
>>> s = 'foo'
>>> s
'foo'
>>> print s
foo
```

When you type any expression into the Python interpreter, if said expression returns a value, the interpreter will output that value's representation, or `repr`.  `repr`s are primarily used for debugging, and are intended to show the value in a way that is useful for the programmer.  A typical example of a value's `repr` is how `repr('foo')` would output `'foo'`.

When you use `print`, you aren't returning a value and so the interpreter is not actually outputting anything; instead, `print` is writing the value's `str` to `sys.stdout` (or an alternative stream, if you specify it with the `>>` syntax, e.g. `print >>sys.stderr, x`).  `str`s are intended for general output, not just programmer use, though they may be the same as `repr`.  A typical example of a value's `str` is how `str('foo')` would output `foo`.

The difference between what the interpreter does and what `print` comes more into play when you write modules or scripts.  `print` statements will continue to produce output, while expression values are not output unless you do so explicitly.  You can still output a value's `repr`, though: `print repr(value)`

You can also control `str` and `repr` in your own objects:

```
>>> class MyThing(object):
...     def __init__(self, value):
...         self.value = value
...     def __str__(self):
...         return str(self.value)
...     def __repr__(self):
...         return '<MyThing value=' + repr(self.value) + '>'
...
>>> mything = MyThing('foo')
>>> mything
<MyThing value='foo'>
>>> print mything
foo
```

Answer (score 4):

In interactive mode, the difference is negligible, as the other answers indicate.

However, in a script, `print a[0]` will actually print output to the screen, while just `a[0]` will *return* the value, but that has no visible effect.

For example, consider the following script, `printtest.py`:

```
myList = ["first", "second", "third"]

print "with print:", myList[0], myList[2]

"without print:", myList[0], myList[2]
```

If you run this script in a terminal (`python printtest.py`), the output is:

> > > with print: first third

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> a=("first","second")
>>> print a[0],a[1]
first second
>>> a[0],a[1]
('first', 'second')
```

Answer (score 1):

> **print() and not using it?**

`print` prints value (*What I mean is in following example, read comets I added*):

```
>>> print a[1]
second           # prints without '
>>> a[1]
'second'         # prints with '
```

more  useful:

print:

```
>>> print "a\nb"  
a                # print value   
b
```

but interpreter

```
>>> "a\na"       # raw strings 
'a\na'
```

that is raw:

```
>>> print repr("a\na")
'a\na'
```

> difference: **print (a[0] a[2]) and a[0] a[2]?**

This print two elements of `a` tuple.  as below

```
>>> print a[0], a[2]
first third
```

this is similar to print two strings like below:

```
>>> print "one", "two"
one two
```

**[second]**

Where as this first create a tuple `(a[0], a[2])` then that will be printed

```
>>> print (a[0], a[2])
('first', 'third')
```

first make a tuple of 2 strings then print that like below:

```
>>> print ("one", "two")
('one', 'two')
```

Additionally, if you add `,` then it makes a tuple:

simple string

```
>>> a[0]
'first'
```

and this is tuple:

```
>>> a[0],
('first',)
```

similarly,

```
>>> a[0], a[1]
('first', 'second')
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
>>> print (a[0], a[2], a[3])
('first', 'second', 'third')
```

try it :)

Comment: No you can't, it would give an IndexError. Besides, this doesn't answer the question.