# Why does print with and without parentheses give __str__() and __repr__() in

Tags: python, maya

I am trying to accomplish some rigging tasks in Autodesk's Maya (2015) using Python. I have run into something I think is odd:

```
for source, destination in SCENE.Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.connections(c=1,p=1):
    print source, destination
```

Gives the following output, the `__str__()` of the Attributes:

```
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateX Left_BallFoot.rotateX
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateY Left_BallFoot.rotateY
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateZ Left_BallFoot.rotateZ
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateOrder Left_BallFoot.rotateOrder
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintParentInverseMatrix Left_BallFoot.parentInverseMatrix[0]
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintJointOrient Left_BallFoot.jointOrient
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetRotate Left_Toe_Control.rotate
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetRotateOrder Left_Toe_Control.rotateOrder
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetParentMatrix Left_Toe_Control.parentMatrix[0]
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetJointOrient Left_Toe_Control.jointOrient
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetWeight Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.Left_ToeControlW0
Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.Left_ToeControlW0 Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetWeight
```

But with parentheses around the print statement's arguments:

```
for source, destination in SCENE.Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.connections(c=1,p=1):
    print(source, destination)
```

The resulting output is this, the `__repr__()` return value:

```
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateX'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.rotateX'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateY'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.rotateY'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateZ'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.rotateZ'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintRotateOrder'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.rotateOrder'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintParentInverseMatrix'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.parentInverseMatrix[0]'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.constraintJointOrient'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot.jointOrient'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetRotate'), Attribute(u'Left_Toe_Control.rotate'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetRotateOrder'), Attribute(u'Left_Toe_Control.rotateOrder'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetParentMatrix'), Attribute(u'Left_Toe_Control.parentMatrix[0]'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetJointOrient'), Attribute(u'Left_Toe_Control.jointOrient'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetWeight'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.Left_ToeControlW0'))
(Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.Left_ToeControlW0'), Attribute(u'Left_BallFoot_orientConstraint.target[0].targetWeight'))
```

Comment: See this for [reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even though it looks like you're making a function call, you are not.  In python 2, `print` is a keyword. So your 2nd example is really:

```
print (source, destination)
```

i.e. you are printing a *tuple*. So, what you are getting is actually the `str` of the `tuple`, which shows the `repr` of its parts.

In recent versions of python, you can get the print function in python 2 for compatibility, by using

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

Then this will do what you expected (but your first example becomes invalid).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense, I had actually just read about the differences between Python 2 and 3 and how in Python 3, `print` is a function. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 3):

In this case here:

```
print source, destination
```

You are calling `print` with two arguments. What `print` will do is call `__str__()` on each argument, and display it.

The second case here:

```
print(source, destination)
```

is actually interpreted as this:

```
print (source, destination)
```

It is converting it to a tuple, and passing it to `print` as one argument. In that case it calls `__str__()` on the tuple, which will call `__repr__()` on each of its elements.

Comment: I upvoted you too robbrit. FatalError was a bit faster though so he gets the green tick. Thanks for your answer!