# Why isn't this a string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, if-statement

Can anyone explain why its printing `failed`? `word` is a string but it keeps jumping to the `else`.

```
word = input("Enter a word.. ")
word_length = len(word)
first_letter = word[0]
last_letter = word[word_length-1]

if word == str:
    print(last_letter + word[1 : word_length-1] + first_letter)
else:
    print("failed")
```

Comment: Did you try `print(word)` and `print(str)`? I think you'd be surprised at the results.

Comment: @thefourtheye: As [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#whitespace-in-expressions-and-statements), `word[word_length-1]` is recommended.

Comment: By the way a simpler way to get the right-most letter in a string is to index from the right using a negative offset, for example `last_letter = word[-1]`.  Negative offsets work with all Python sequences, which include string, lists, and tuples.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you say

```
if word == str:
```

you are checking if the `word` is the same as the [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-str) function.

---

If you want to check if the input is a string, then you can use the 
[`isinstance()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) function, like this

```
if isinstance(word, str):
```

---

But [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) function, in Python 3.x, always returns a string only. So, you don't have to check if the input is a string or not.

---

**Note:** In case, you are using Python 2.x, `print` is actually a statement, not a function. You can read more about that in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6182964/1903116).

Comment: `if word == str:` checks against the string object. If he were using `if word == str():` then that's the same as checking if word is an empty string. As `str()` on it's own returns an empty string