# print statement comma acting weird in python

Tags: python, printing

When I code:

```
x = 4
y = 10

print("X is", x, "and Y is", y)
```

I get as a result:

```
('X is', 4, 'and Y is', 10)
```

Instead of:

```
X is 4 and Y is 10
```

Why is this happening? Please help.

Comment: You are creating a tuple.

Comment: You do get: `X is 4 and Y is 10`, at least in Python 3 which expects `(..)` for `print`. What version of Python is this?

Comment: You're using Python 2, and that `print` statement is printing a tuple. If you want to use the `print` _function_  instead (and you should), put this at the start of your script: `from __future__ import print_function`.

Comment: I'm sure this question has been asked before, but I can't find a good duplicate target, although this one is fairly close: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6182964/why-is-parenthesis-in-print-voluntary-in-python-2-7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be using python 2, where `print` is a *keyword* instead of a function.  It is interpreting the comma-separated items inside the parentheses as a tuple, and so it is printing the tuple.

Just remove the parentheses and it will work as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Just do it the modern way with string formatting

```
print "x is {0} and y is {1}".format(x, y)
```

Or old school

```
print "x is " + str(x) + " and y is " + str(y)
```

or use

```
print("X is %d and Y is %d" % (x, y))
```

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Mahesh :D I was about to press edit to do this, saved me time!

Comment: The modern way is to stop using Python 2 and migrate to Python 3. ;) But if you can't do that for some reason, it's a Good Idea to use the `__future__` import, to make it easier to write code that runs correctly on both versions.

Comment: I agree @PM2Ring with `__future__` is the way to go if you do packages, but if someone just started with Python, i like your first idea more..