# What does end=' ' in a print call exactly do?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm struggling to understand this exercise:

```
def a(n):
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            if i == 0 or i == n-1 or j == 0 or j == n-1:
                print('*',end='')
            else:
                print(' ',end='')
        print()
```

which prints an empty square. I thought I could use the code

```
print("*", ''*(n-2),"*")
```

to print the units in between the upper and the lower side of the square but they won't be aligned to the upper/lower side ones, which doesn't happen if you run the first code.

So, could this be because of `end=''` or `print()`?

Would you be so kind and tell me what do they mean?

Comment: This are named or keyword parameters: http://docs.python.org/release/1.5.1p1/tut/keywordArgs.html

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end

Comment: @NilaniAlgiriyage I've also found that question and I don't think it's a duplicate. The question you found is mainly discussing the difference between `Python2` and `Python3` since there is no argument `end` for `print` in `Python2` (actually in `Python2` `print` is not a function but a statement). And this OP is trying to know what `end` does.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check the [reference page of `print`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#print). By default there is a newline character appended to the item being printed (`end='\n'`), and `end=''` is used to make it printed on the same line.

And `print()` prints an empty newline, which is necessary to keep on printing on the next line.

**EDITED:** added an example.
Actually you could also use this:

```
def a(n):
    print('*' * n)
    for i in range(n - 2):
        print('*' + ' ' * (n - 2) + '*')
    if n > 1:
        print('*' * n)
```

Comment: Or, in a single call to `print`: `print( '*' * n + '\n' + ( '*' + ' '*(n-2) + '*\n' )*(n-2) + '*'*n )`

Comment: @Robᵩ Of course there're many ways to write the code short, however this is not something like IOCCC and the purpose of source code is for people to read. I don't see any benefit to write like that. Also, are you sure you're providing a _correct_ example? You may try `n=1`.

Answer (score 1):

In Python 3.x, the end=' ' is used to place a space after the displayed string instead of a newline.

please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end) for a further explanation.

Answer (score 0):

print() uses some separator when it has more than one parameter. In your code you have 3 ("*" is first, ''*(n-2) - second, "*" -third). If you don't want to use separator between them add sep='' as key-word parameter.

```
print("*", ' '*(n-2), "*", sep='')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']
    i = 0
    for i in range(len (spam)):
        if i == len(spam) -1:
            print ('and', spam[i])
        elif i == len (spam) -2:
            print (spam [i], end=' ')
        else:
            print (spam [i], end=', ')
```

So I'm new to this whole coding thing, but I came up with this code. It's probably not as sophisticated as the other stuff, but it does the job.

```
spam = ['apples', 'bananas', 'tofu', 'cats']    
def fruits():
    i = 0
    while i != len(spam):
        if len(spam) != i :
            print ('and', spam[i])
            i += 1   
 fruits()
```

try this!

Answer (score 0):

use this to understand

```
for i in range(0,52):
    print(5*"fiof" ,end=" ")
```

just put different things here in end and also use with sep

Answer (score 0):

```
spam=['apples','bananas','tofu','cats']
def fruits():
    i=0
    while (i<len(spam)):
           if(i!=(len(spam)-1)):
              print(spam[i],end=', ')
           else:
                print("and",spam[i])
           i=i+1
fruits()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35746505)

Comment: @MattSeymour: Can you explain _why_ this isn’t an answer?

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Answer (score -3):

```
print('\n'.join('*{}*'.format((' ' if 0<row<n-1 else '*')*n-2) for row in range(n)))
```

Comment: It's absolutely sure if you could write code without testing -- as long as they are correct. However in this case it's not. There are currently two syntax errors to be fixed in your answer, and also another bug that your code doesn't handle the case when `n==1`.