# Python 3.4.2 Output Formatting

Tags: python

I have written a code in Python that includes a loop that provides 100 answers pertaining to one variable. So for example the output looks like this when I run it in the shell: (top to bottom)

```
1   
2  
3     
4  
5   
etc...
```

How do I format this to show 10 outputs per line: (left to right)

```
1  2  3  4  5
```

Here is my code:

```
def main():

n = 0

while n <= 100:
    if getPentagonalNumber(n):
        n += 1
        number = (n * (3*n - 1)) / 2
        print (format(number, "5.0f"), end = ' ')


def getPentagonalNumber(n):

    for n in range (1, 100):
        if n > 100:
            return False
    return True

main()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python print end=' '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)

Comment: like `' '.join(['1', '2', '3'])`

Comment: Could you please show your code? What did you try?

Comment: I tried the solution of using: print(i, end = ' '). It worked, but I need to show 10 outputs per line, how do I do this?

Comment: What are you exactly trying to do in the function `getPentagonalNumber`? It seems to always return `True`.

Comment: I'm new at functions and this was the only version of code that seemed to work, so I left it alone. Would it work without the False condition?

Comment: @RyanCombs: There are a number of logic issues with your code (unrelated to your questions about printing). Your `while` loop will run forever if `getPentagonalNumber` ever returns anything but `True`, since the `n` value is only incremented within the `if` statement. That said, `getPentagonalNumber` isn't a very useful function, since it ignores its argument and simply loops from `1` to `99` and confirms that none of those values are greater than `100`. I suggest using `for` loop on a `range` instead of the `while`, and making `getPentagonalNumber` do something useful.

Answer (score 0):

try the following

```
print(i, end=' ')
```

EDIT: If you want to print 10 numbers per line, you can do something like this

```
if i%10==0:
    print('')
```

This will add a new line after every 10 numbers. (Note: This is assuming that `i` is the loop variable which is incremented once in every iteration)

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. I actually need to print 10 answers per line. How would that be approached?

Comment: @RyanCombs: That's a different question to what you originally asked! There are a few different ways to print 10 answers per line. Which way is the most suitable depends on your code. So ask a new question, showing us some relevant code so we can see what you're loop is doing.

Comment: @RyanCombs I have edited the answer according to your comment.

Comment: I apologize for the struggle and I appreciate your help. I edited the original question and included my code.