# Python 3.x print(end = "") Error

Tags: python, ide

I've tried using both Netbeans and PyCharm, but the same error keeps popping up.  The error is when I use end="" as instructed by my tutorial it throws different errors depending on what IDE I'm using.  Am I completely typing it incorrectly or can someone give me some advice as to what to do

```
__author__ = "Kevin"
__date__ = "$May 24, 2015 9:23:37 PM$"

print("Pink", end="")
print("Octopus")
```

The error code in Netbeans is

```
No viable alternative at input '='

mismatched input '""' expecting RPAREN
----
(Alt-Enter shows hints)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [python print end=' '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)

Answer (score 0):

What's most likely happening here is that you are using a Python3 tutorial, but your interpreter in PyCharm and Netbeans is Python2.

In Python2 `print` was a statement, whereas in [Python3 it's a function](https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html#print-is-a-function).

You should be able to fix this by importing the `print` function in Python2 from the future module:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print("Pink", end="")  # now works in Python2
```

Alternativey, you can update PyCharm to use the Python3 interpreter. [See here how to set the interpreter](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-python-interpreter-for-a-project.html).

Comment: Thank you.  I will just update the interpreter to the proper version.  I appreciate your time.