# Im trying to print a series of strings on the same line

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

I'm trying to print three strings next to each other like so:

```
       StringA   StringB   StringC
```

However, whenever I run my code no matter what I've tried it always prints them on different lines. How do I fix this? 
My code is as follows:

```
def DisplayCard(row, column, array):
   x=0
   t=""
   while x < column:
      s = array[x]
      t = ''.join(s)
      x=x+1
      print(t),
```

Where array is the data passed into the function in the form of a list. Also forgot to mention im running 2.7

Comment: Can you please explain with input values for all `row`/`column`/`array`  and the expected output for that?

Comment: I'm assuming [python 3](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#print)?

Comment: Your easy way to do that would be `print(t, end="")`

Comment: This might be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598181/python-print-on-same-line

Comment: @NightShadeQueen Nope. That print statement implies python2.

Comment: Im trying to print strings in a grid format so that's what the row and column parameters are for.

Comment: Im running 2.7, none of these suggestions have been successful so far

Comment: `from __future__ import print_function` ?https://docs.python.org/2/library/__future__.html

Comment: @Benschilibowl: Are you sure that the input doesn't contain newlines?

Comment: So you want to print the first n*m things from array, arranged in rows and columns?

Comment: @AaronDigulla It's quite possible since I'm reading them from a text file.  How would i remove the new lines from the input?

Comment: @Benschilibowl see my answer for a test and a solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `print(thing, end = '')`. That should work fine

```
def DisplayCard(row, column, array):
   x=0
   t=""
   while x < column:
      s = array[x]
      t = ''.join(s).replace("\n", "")
      x=x+1
      print(t, end = ''),
```

Either that or append them to one string

```
def DisplayCard(row, column, array):
   x=0
   t=""
   while x < column:
      s = array[x]
      t += ''.join(s).replace("\n", "")
      x=x+1
   print(t)
```

Comment: The extra comma is python2 syntax to print on the same line.

Comment: I tried this but it still prints on different lines

Comment: Thanks @Bhargav Rao , I'm used to Python 3 lol. Try using the second code Benschilibowl

Comment: Welcome, you probably had `\n` in your array as multiple others have said

Comment: @ytpillai Nope. The OP is using Python2.7. The `print` he is using has a trailing comma. Apart from that the OP has clarified on the point. (And please do check the spelling of my name before posting)

Comment: My apologies for both, I realized now and deleted that comment. I made a typo spelling your name @BhargavRao

Answer (score 3):

You habe 3 possibilities:

- create a big string which you print at the end
- [`print(text, end="")`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print), see https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456292/562769
- use the system module: `sys.out.write`, see
  [How to print without newline or space?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/493386)

Answer (score 2):

`print(t),` should work unless `t` contains a newline. Use `print repr(t),` to find out. If you now see `\n`, then the `array` contains newline characters which you need to remove first.

If the newlines are at the end of the string, you can remove them with `t.strip()`. If they are in the middle, use `t.replace('\n', '')`

Comment: Probably just safe to use `.replace()`