# Print Number 1-10 in python - Error: no viable alternative at input '='

Tags: python, python-2.7, jython, jython-2.7

Here's my code:

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i, end=' ')  #This line is throwing an error
```

`SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input '='`

I am using Netbeans and Jython 2.7.0

Comment: I think @zondo is right. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end

Answer (score 4):

You tagged it with python-2.7 and python-3.x, but that shouldn't throw a problem in Python3.

The problem there is that in Python2, `print` is a statement, so `end = ' '` is invalid syntax.

To get the same result, either put `from __future__ import print_function` at the beginning of the script, or say `print i,` instead.

Comment: Getting `SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input '='` error even after the import in Jython 2.7.0`. Works in cPython though.