# Eclipse PyDev bug? end="" gives me a syntax error

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I have the latest PyDev plug in on Eclipse Neon. When I copy/paste my code from IDLE to PyDev I get an error on PyDev about `end=''` being a syntax error. `end=''` means to continue printing on the same line but it gives me an error.

```
class ShiftLeft:
    def __init__(self, inputList = []):
        self._list1 = inputList

    def Print(self):
        print('Inside def Print(self): ', end='')
        print(self._list1)

    def ShiftL(self):
        temp = len(self._list1)
        lastValue = self._list1[temp-1]

        for i in range(temp-1, 0, -1):
            self._list1[i] = self._list1[i-1]

        self._list1[0] = lastValue

def main():
    testList = [123,23523,12312,2523]
    #testList.sort()
    print(testList)
    print()

    hey = ShiftLeft(testList)
    hey.ShiftL()
    hey.ShiftL()
    hey.Print()

main()
```

The error is this

```
print('Inside def Print(self): ', end=' ')
                                     ^
```

> SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Ive tried looking for the answer for about 30 minutes with no luck.

Comment: Are you using python 2 or 3? This isn't available in python 2.X

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python print end=' '](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)