# Why invalid syntax (<string>, line 24)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax-error

Super new to Python and I just can't figure out what is causing the error message in my code...

```
It says '[pylint] E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 24)'.
```

Could anyone maybe explain what I'm missing here?

Much thanks!

```
#########################################
# Draws a mario-style right-side-aligned half pyramid 
# of the requested height.
# Restriction: 0 < height < 23
##########################################

while True:
    height = int(input("Height: "))
    if height > 0 and height < 23:
        break
    elif height == 0:
        print()
        print()
        print()
        print("I have drawn a pyramid with a height of 0!")
        print("Isn't it pretty!")
        exit(0)

hashes = 2

for i in range(height):
    spaces = (height - hashes + 1)
    for j in range(spaces):
        print(" ", end="")
    for k in range(hashes):
        print("#", end="" )
    print()
    hashes += 1
```

Comment: Can you include the _full_ error you are receiving? Also, which is line 24?

Comment: Sorry! 
Line 24 is: 
    print(" ", end="")
And the message in full is:
severity: 'Error'
message: 'E0001:invalid syntax (<string>, line 24)'
at: '24,1'
source: 'pylint'

Comment: Are you sure you're on Python 3?

Comment: Which version of Python are you using?  Try `import sys;  print(sys.version)`

Comment: Line 17 or line 24? Which is it?

Comment: sorry was still trying to fix it, deleting some parts, but it is in line 24, the line print(" ", end=""). I edited my comment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python print end=' '](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)

Comment: How are you running your program? Pylint is an external tool.

Answer (score 2):

You are using python2 and should change:

```
print(" ", end="")
print("#", end="" )
```

to:

```
print(" "),
print("#"),
```

---

**furthermore**

You should probably change:

```
print()
```

to

```
print("")
```

And this "beauty" can be reduced by using "\n" which translates rowbreak.

```
print()
print()
print()
print("I have drawn a pyramid with a height of 0!")
print("Isn't it pretty!")
```

to:

```
print("\n\n\nI have drawn a pyramid with a height of 0!\nIsn't it pretty!")
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on style improvement! 

However I am sure that I'm using Python3.
'import sys; print(sys.version)' returned:

3.6.2 (default, Oct  2 2017, 09:48:04)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609]

Comment: @wvandertoorn That is strange as I have both py2 and py3 and have replicated your error on py2. Your could works fine on 3.6.

Comment: @wvandertoorn `python3` may be 3.6.2, but what about `pylint`?

Comment: Also, `from __future__ import print_function` is probably a better way to handle a version mismatch, rather than "fixing" all the `print` calls, assuming the version being used is at least 2.6.

Comment: @trentcl well that is arguable as I was under the assumption he wrote the code in py2. Most likely the problem is something else here though.

Comment: The question is tagged [python-3.x] so I assumed that Python 3 was intended. Nevertheless, I still advocate for time travel to the future over time travel to the past :)

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR: Try install pylint3**

```
sudo apt-get install pylint3
```

---

Today I had a nearly identical issue. I wanted to use pyreverse, but the mentioned syntax error message occurred. I have had installed both python2 and python3 so assumed that pyreverse (pylint) was just using python2, so I changed my python symlink (python2 was the default):

```
sudo ln -sfn /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/bin/python
```

But this didn’t help, so I looked if pylint haves pylint3 version and It haves. After installing pylint3 and running pyreverse3 (for your case pylint3) everything runs just fine.

I know this is an old question, but for someone else this could be helpful.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed my problem by using `pyreverse3`. Probably that would also be good hint in the more general pyreverse questions.