# The end=' ' option in print function in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried running the following program:

```
for i in range(5):
  print(i, end=' ')
```

However, it waits for me to write some string in the next line and gives the output like:

```
0 1 2 3 4 'Hi'
```

where 'Hi' is what I input. I'm using the latest version 3.6.5 and can't seem to understand the reason behind this error. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 3):

The *default* value for `end` is `'\n'`, meaning that `print()` will write a newline character after printing the arguments. This would put the cursor on the next line.

Usually, `stdout` (to which `print()` writes by default) is also *line buffered*, meaning that data written to it is not flushed (and shown on your terminal) until a newline character is seen, to signal the end of the line.

You replaced the newline with a space, so no newline is written; instead a space is written, letting you write successive numbers one after the other on the same line.

Add an extra, empty `print()` call after your `for` loop to write the newline after looping:

```
for i in range(5):
    print(i, end=' ')

print()
```

You could also add `flush=True` to the `print(..., end=' ')` calls to explicitly flush the buffer.

Alternatively, for a small enough `range()`, pass in the values to `print()` as separate arguments, leaving `end` at the default. Separate arguments are separated by the `sep` argument, by default set to a space:

```
print(*range(5))
```

The `*` in front of the `range()` object tells Python to loop over the `range()` object and pass all values that produces as separate arguments to the `print()` call; so all 5 numbers are printed with spaces in between and a newline character at the end:

```
>>> print(*range(5))
0 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks. This did the trick. However, I referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31709208/9847180) answer and still can't understand why that works and mine doesn't.I also tried a code to print characters in a string like mantra = "Always look on the bright side" and python still asks for a string prompt when I run the end = ' ' in print function.

Comment: Good answer, but I think the OP's question was asking why his code is waiting for an input rather than simply print `0 1 2 3 4 ` (although I couldn't reproduce it)

Comment: @A.B. Yas! That's exactly why I can't wrap my head around the fact that an empty print function makes the code work.

Comment: @KranKran: Right, updated my answer to explain why you don't see the line until there is a newline character. This is due to *line buffering*; the `stdout` file object holds on to data to minimise (slow) write operations. The idea is to collect multiple small writes into one big one, every time there is a newline character in the buffer.

Comment: I guess the follow-up question would be why those two lines of code, for OP, wait for an input, while when I try to run the same code, it instead prints and does not wait for an input

Comment: @A.B.: that's already been added to my answer. The 'input' flushes the buffer when they hit enter (which adds a newline)

Comment: @MartijnPieters I might not have been clear in my comment: When I run the same code as the OP, I am not prompted to enter any input; it simply prints. I was wondering why it would act differently for me versus the OP

Comment: @A.B.: it depends on the console or terminal, and how the Python code is being run.