# How to change python version from 2.x to 3.x in Sublime text 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, sublimetext3

Currently I have installed sublime text 3 in Linux for python programming. 
When I am executing the piece of code, I am getting error, this error is because of Python version sublime 3 is using is 2.7. How  can i change the python version from 2.x to latest 3.x in sublime text 3.
Here is my piece of code

```
lis = [2, 1, 3, 5, 4]
# using len() to print length of list
print ("The length of list is : ", end="")
print (len(lis))
# using min() to print minimum element of list
print ("The minimum element of list is : ", end="")
print (min(lis))
# using max() to print maximum element of list
print ("The maximum element of list is : ", end="")
print (max(lis))
```

When I am running this program on python 2.x version, I am getting an error as "invalid syntax", but this error is not coming in python 3.x version. 
Kindly guide me to change the python version of sublime text 3 from 2.x to 3.x

Comment: *Clarification: I am getting the error message here: print ("The length of list is : ", end="")

Comment: Could you specify what your error message is, to ensure the correct problem is addressed?

Comment: To work in python2, use `print "The minimum element of list is : {}".format(min(ls))`.

Comment: You are asking how to solve the problem in python2 or how to change the python version in sublime text? Because your question and accepted answer do not match

Comment: I want to change the python version in sublime text.

Comment: @debaonline4u I see you accepted an answer which is **not** telling you how to do that, it may be misleading

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end) question.

You cannot run the statement `print('something: ', end='')` in python 2. The reason being `print` is a literal in Python2 and cannot take arguments. Whereas in Python3, print is a function.

In order to print something like that in Python2, you can use this syntax -

`print "The length of list is : ",`

Notice the comma at the end of the statement.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2456148/python-print-end)

Comment: If this solves your doubt, either upvote or mark this as the answer. Desperately need some reputation. :P

Comment: got it. appreciate.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to change the python version in Sublime Text, first of all you have to install the [two Python versions](https://www.python.org/downloads/) and know where you actually installed them.
Ensure that by the cmd line you can call a .py script with python2 and python3.
Then, in sublime text, go in `Tools --> Build System --> New Build System...`.
In the windows that opens, copy-paste this code:

```
{
    "cmd": ["python3", "-i", "-u", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^[ ]File \"(...?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
    "selector": "source.python"
}
```

and save this script as `Python3.sublime-build`

you should now have the following values in `Tools --> Build System`:

```
Python # which is your Python2
Python3 # which is your Python3
```

**note** that where we wrote `"python3"`, if that's not working, you may put the path to your python3 installation, such as `"/usr/bin/python3"`

Check at the end of [this discussion](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/select-which-version-of-python-to-run-build/1695/9) for some tips.