# Print on same line on sikuli IDE

Tags: python, jython, sikuli, sikuli-ide

I am trying to print several things on the same line using different calls on the Sikuli IDE, but I'm apparently unable to do so.

What I would do on python as:

```
print("Doing a sum: ", end="")
x=2+5
print(x)

>> Doing a sum: 7
```

On Sikuli IDE (2.0.5 for what is worth), I'm getting this error (line 44 is where the print is):

```
[error] script [ test_framework ] stopped with error in line 44 at column 54
[error] SyntaxError ( "mismatched input '=' expecting RPAREN",  )
```

I've tried different combinations as well as parameters (some `flush=True` as well), but to no avail.

Did anyone ever try this before? Any solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Sikulix website:

[image: languages support]

while the `print` line you are trying to run must be ran using Python 3. It won't work with Python 2.7. You can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2456292/1119381) to get more details.